# Unable to Arrange And Space my of code using Java Fx?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

This is my code. It is a java fx project. My problem is with display purposed. I have attached a photo below. I don't know how to space the items correctly and the textbox are all misplaced. This program is indented to take in customer input and calculate the charge of their phone bill. That might be irrelevant because I am just focused on the appearance of the code. Any Help will be greatly appreciated. I am a new coder.  Thank you!!

```
package phonebill;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class PhoneBill extends Application {

    private final String TITLE = "PHONE BILL";
    private static final double OVER_LIMIT_CHARGE = 15.0;
    private TextArea receipt;
    private TextField custPlan = new TextField();
    private TextField gbUsed = new TextField();
    private TextField custName = new TextField();
    private double totalBill;
    private final Tariff[] tariffList = {
        new Tariff("A", 0, 50),
        new Tariff("B", 2, 60),
        new Tariff("C", 4, 70),
        new Tariff("D", 10, 90),};

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        System.out.println("hi-1");
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(Title());

        System.out.println("hi-2");
        //root.setLeft(leftBox());
        root.setCenter(centerPane());
        root.setBottom(Buttons());
        System.out.println("hi-2.1");
        //root.setRight(rightBox());
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #F0E0C0;");
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10)); // spacing between nodes
        System.out.println("hi-2.2");
        //BorderPane.setMargin(receipt, new Insets(5, 10, 0, 5));
        System.out.println("hi-3");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle(TITLE);
        System.out.println("hi-4");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private HBox centerPane() {
        HBox centerPanel = new HBox();
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        ColumnConstraints tariffData = new ColumnConstraints();
        ColumnConstraints customerData = new ColumnConstraints();
        ColumnConstraints customerBillData = new ColumnConstraints();
        tariffData.setPercentWidth(25);
        customerData.setPercentWidth(50);
        customerBillData.setPercentWidth(25);
        grid.getColumnConstraints().add(tariffData);
        grid.getColumnConstraints().add(customerData);
        grid.getColumnConstraints().add(customerBillData);

        grid.add(leftBox(), 0, 0);
        grid.add(centerBox(), 1, 0);
        grid.add(rightBox(), 2, 0);
        centerPanel.getChildren().add(grid);
        return centerPanel;
    }

    private VBox centerBox() {
        VBox customerData = new VBox();
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(5);
        ColumnConstraints column1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        column1.setPrefWidth(50);
        grid.getColumnConstraints().add(column1);

        Label title = new Label();
        title.setText("Customer Data");
        grid.add(title, 0, 0);
        Label custNameBP = new Label();
        custNameBP.setText("Name");
        grid.add(custNameBP, 0, 1);
        custName.setText("");
        grid.add(custName, 0, 2);
        custPlan.setText("");
        grid.add(custPlan, 0, 3);
        Label planBP = new Label();
        planBP.setText("Plan");
        grid.add(planBP, 1, 3);
        gbUsed.setText("");
        grid.add(gbUsed, 0, 4);
        customerData.getChildren().add(grid);
        return customerData;
    }

    private VBox rightBox() {
        VBox finalBill = new VBox();
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(5);
        ColumnConstraints column1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        column1.setPrefWidth(50);
        grid.getColumnConstraints().add(column1);

        Label title = new Label();
        title.setText("Customer Bill");
        grid.add(title, 0, 0);

        Label custNameBP = new Label();
        custNameBP.setText("Customer's Name : " + custName.getText());
        grid.add(custNameBP, 0, 1);

        Label custBill = new Label();
        custBill.setText("Please Pay : " + totalBill);
        grid.add(custBill, 0, 1);

        finalBill.getChildren().add(grid);
        return finalBill;
    }

    private VBox leftBox() {
        VBox plansAndPrices = new VBox();
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();

        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(5);
        ColumnConstraints column1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        column1.setPrefWidth(50);
        grid.getColumnConstraints().add(column1);
        //VBox customerData = new VBox();
        //VBox custBill = new VBox();
        for (int row = 0; row < tariffList.length; row++) {
            Label gb = new Label();
            Label gbRate = new Label();
            gb.setText(Integer.toString(tariffList[row].getGb()) + " GB");
            gbRate.setText("$" + Double.toString(tariffList[row].getGbRate()));
            grid.add(gb, 0, row);
            grid.add(gbRate, 1, row);

        }

        plansAndPrices.getChildren().add(grid);
        return plansAndPrices;
    }

    private HBox Title() {  // Border TOP
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Font font36B = Font.font("Ariel", FontWeight.BOLD, 36); // title
        Label lblTitle = new Label(TITLE);
        lblTitle.setFont(font36B);
        hbox.getChildren().add(lblTitle);
        return hbox;
    }

    private HBox Buttons() {  // Border BOTTOM
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setSpacing(20.0);  // spacing between the buttons
        hbox.setPrefHeight(50); // spacing around the top/bottom of buttons
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); // center the buttons on the row

        Button btnTotal = new Button("Compute");
        btnTotal.setPrefSize(100, 20);    // make each button the same size
        btnTotal.setOnAction(e -> computeTotal());
        // btnTotal.setOnKeyPressed (e -> computeTotal());

        Button btnClear = new Button("Clear");
        btnClear.setPrefSize(100, 20);
        //btnClear.setOnAction (e -> Clear());
        //btnClear.setOnKeyPressed (e -> Clear());

        Button btnExit = new Button("Exit");
        btnExit.setPrefSize(100, 20);
        btnExit.setOnAction(e -> System.exit(0));
        btnExit.setOnKeyPressed(e -> System.exit(0));

        hbox.getChildren().addAll(btnTotal, btnClear, btnExit);
        return hbox;
    }

    /**
     * TextArea setReceipt() creates a TextArea to be used as the customer's
     * receipt
     */
    private TextArea Receipt() {
        receipt = new TextArea();
        Font fontCourierNew = Font.font("Courier New", FontWeight.BOLD, 14);
        receipt.setFont(fontCourierNew);
        receipt.setPrefWidth(460.0);
        return receipt;
    }

    private void computeTotal() {
        System.out.println(this.custPlan.getText());
        double overLimit;

        Tariff custTariff = new Tariff();
        custTariff = getTariff(this.custPlan.getText());
        int used = new Integer(gbUsed.getText()).intValue();
        if (used <= custTariff.getGb()) // see if customer used more GB than is on the plan
        {
            overLimit = 0.0;
        } else {
            overLimit = Math.ceil(used - custTariff.getGb());
        }
        // the bill is the plan's base rate + any charge for GB over the plan limit
        totalBill = custTariff.getGbRate() + overLimit * OVER_LIMIT_CHARGE;
        System.out.println("Total Bill : " + totalBill);

    }

    private Tariff getTariff(String planName) {
        Tariff custTariff = new Tariff();
        for (int i = 0; i < tariffList.length; i++) {
            if (tariffList[i].getPlan().equals(planName)) {
                custTariff = tariffList[i];
            }
        }
        return custTariff;
    }

}
```

Comment: You're going to have to come up with a better problem description than "all misplaced." Where are the textboxes supposed to go? What's happening instead?

Comment: I don't see the screenshot that's supposed to be part of the question. The description of the desired behaviour doesn't seem sufficient to get the desired behaviour accross either. Pelase add this info to the question.

Comment: The title "Unable to Arrange And Space my of code using Java Fx?" is meaningless to me. Perhaps there's a missing word between 'my' and 'of.